# JSON Quotes Being Unescaped In POST

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, escaping, decode

I have a piece of code that accepts a JSON string as a POST parameter. The challenge I'm having is how the string is decoded. Consider a post to `mygateway.php` with a field `meta` of:

```
{"test" : "One \"quote\" is as good as an escaped \"quote\"..."}
```

If I run:

```
$meta_json_string = $this->CI->post('meta', true);
```

The value of $meta_json_string is:

```
{
    "test": "One "quote" is as good as an escaped "quote"..."
}
```

This fails to decode when run through `json_decode()`. Any suggestions on how to prevent CodeIgniter from unescaping the quotes so I can decode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
$meta_json_string = $this->CI->post('meta');
```

This way CI will not be running the XSS sanitation on the string which is too complex to reliably sanitize being a JSON string. Once you do the above then `json_decode()` it and then run `$this->security->xss_clean()` individually on the elements you are wanting to echo out.

Comment: I actually tried that and it didn't seem to make any difference.